# How to make horizontal navigation bar using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this simple code in HTML using Bootstrap classes to create a navigation bar. I want my navigation bar to be horizontal so I added the `navbar-inverse` class. However, my navigation bar keeps showing vertical and I can't figure out why it does that even thought I tried different things to fix it.

```html
<div class="blog-masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">New features</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do what you describe. https://www.bootply.com/ZvDycROXEW. Post an [mcve] in your question please

Comment: navbar-inverse provides alternate color scheme over default gray theme. It wont affect vertical or horizontal alignment of elements. Please update css used and related code to help further.

Comment: @joan Your code seems to be working fine. I believe some css is overriding bootstrap css or check if bootstrap is included correctly.

Comment: @pratikpawar I think that might be the problem. I saw that the code was working fine too. I need to check which css is doing an override.

Comment: @JoanPlepi You could check it under developer tools explore to nav bar and items and see what all css are being applied to filter out the css code. Hope it helps

Comment: On smaller screens (such as small tablets or smartphones), Bootstrap navigation bars get displayed vertically instead of horizontally [if you don't let them collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h)

Comment: @natejms true. Joan check it out if this is the reason :)

Comment: Look at the answer given by core114 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46486412/4583518. It might be helpful.

Comment: Look at the ans given by core114 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46486412/4583518. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I hope navbar-inverse is nothing to do with menu view style I hope it's used to change the color of the menu text and for the view style you should use nav-link in a tag and nav-toggleable in nav tag I hope it's the answer.

I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question

```
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link  active" href="#">Home</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link " href="#">New features</a>
                 </li>

               </ul>

               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item" href="#">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</a></li>
               </ul>

         </nav>
     </div>
```