# Bootstrap 4, bg-inverse not showing?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Trying to follow the navbar example in Bootstraps documentation, I have a problem where the background colour of the navbar doesn't get loaded.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
</nav>
```

I took a look in bootstrap.css and bg-inverse does not appear there. Am I supposed to create the colours myself, or am I doing something wrong? (I am working in an Angular project)

Comment: Can you add an example with the js file attached, use jsfiddle.

Comment: Do you mean Bootstrap.js?, as this is angular I only have .ts files

Comment: what  are you  used for bootstrap  `bootstrap@4.0.0-beta` or  `bootstrap -v 4.0.0.alpha6 `

Comment: I use bootstrap@4.0.0-beta

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are using `Bootstrap beta` version. Use the `Alpha version`. It will solve the problem , they are not provide bootstrap 4 beta for the  `navbar-inverse bg-inverse`

**bootstrap -v 4.0.0.alpha6**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-primary">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>
```

look at this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

**bootstrap@4.0.0-beta**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>
```

look at this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 8):

**Bootstrap 4** doesn't have css classes `navbar-inverse bg-inverse`. You need to use combination of `navbar-light bg-light` or `navbar-dark bg-dark`with `nav` component. For example:

- `<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </nav>`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap have dropped support for `bg-inverse`.