# Bootstrap nav bar function is not working in django can anyone support?

Tags: python, django, web

I have just trying to create a simple code and in terms of designing it I used bootstrap CDN link and navigation bar is not showing its result. Could you help me with that?
Code is below:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

      </nav>
  {% block body %}
  {% endblock %}    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here it should show me a bar but it is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4, bg-inverse not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485768/bootstrap-4-bg-inverse-not-showing)

Comment: very good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will only show you a bar because you didn't include anything in your `<nav>`. Try this iteration of the navbar instead:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <!-- here are the contents! your navbar didn't show you anything -->
  <!-- because you didn't feed any contents into your navbar -->

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Please comment if this still doesn't work. Also, you might want to include the javascript files:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Yes, you need the css file, but you also need the javascript files for everything to function properly.

Comment: I used it it had worked before I took this code from bootstrap website but my own code is not showing anything. Although I have not included anything due to <nav> it should show me the empty bar but it does not.

Comment: If it does not even have the bar, then try and check whether you've imported all the javascript (3) and css (1) files. If it shows the empty bar, that's what should've happened because you didn't include anything in your `nav`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cant find your navbar in your above mentioned code, I assume that you have your navbar in another file. If that is the case you have to include it like `{% include 'navbar.html' %}` assuming you saved the file as `navbar.html`. Or if your navbar comprises of just two lines which you mentioned here, it ill surely be visible if you change your navbar's color. Moreover I think you also have to include the JS and Jquery CDN links to make your navbar responsive! Hope this helps :)